# Strange String manipulation method

Tags: c#, java, string

My colleague was trying to write a method (In Java/C#) that would append an arbitrary number of zero's to the end of a `String`.  However, I can't seem to figure out what his approach is.

This is the Java code, the C# is basically equivalent:

```
String appendzeros(int input, int no_of_digits_required)
{
    String result = Integer.toString(input);
    int i,j;

    for(i = 10, j = 1; i <= Math.pow(10, no_of_digits_required-1); i = i*10, j++)
    {
        if(input / i == 0)
        {
            for(int k = 1; k <= no_of_digits_required-j; k++)
                result = "0" + result;

            break;
        }                    
    } 

    return result;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What can't you figure out? The code is right there

Comment: Why don't you ask him?

Comment: He's no longer with my company.  Also, @musefan if you haven't noticed, this approach is definetely not the first thing any software engineer would think of, so I have a hard time understanding his approach

Comment: Or why don't you just tell him to stop being a madhead. This could be done so much simpler

Comment: Also, even if it works, it prepends rather than appends zeros.

Comment: Btw, in C# it can be simplified to `input.PadRight(no_of_digits_required, '0');`

Comment: C89-like scoping of iteration variables, an extremely idiomatic way to do what could be written in 4 simple lines... Yeah, I don't think your colleague is very competent. It's not a bad question, but you won't gain anything from understanding the specifics of this approach.

Comment: Any sample input and desired output? I don't think this needs so much code like that.

Comment: @crocboy: Yeah, its a stupid approach, but then perhaps that is why he is no longer with the company.

Comment: I think here is the best place for this code: http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: You really think that "why did my colleague write this?" is not a bad question?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - your code will probably give different results for very large no_of_digits_required. Better results, but still different.

Comment: please remove the C# tag, the code is not basically the same.

Comment: @musefan Yes. There are lots of questions that show some code and ask what it does or how it does what it does. And many of them are upvoted, so they seem to be generally accepted as good questions. And even if they weren't upvoted, I still wouldn't think of them as bad. But I also do understand why someone would view them as bad, not constructive or too localized.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about what a piece of code does.

Comment: The code is incredible... To write it that way, it would have took me at least 4 hours... And tons of unit tests to be sure it was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea of the code is to count how many digits there are in the stringified number, and then add the "padding" zeroes.

Now let's see how...

```
String result = Integer.toString(input);
```

Initial stringification of the number (`5 => "5"`)

```
for(i = 10, j = 1; i <= Math.pow(10, no_of_digits_required-1); i = i*10, j++)
```

`i` will contain powers of 10 (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000....) We know that we can stop at `10^(no_of_digits_required-1)`. Why? We will see it later! `j` is the number of digits of the `input` (it's a counter, we know that it has at least a digit, because even `0` is composed by a digit)

```
if(input / i == 0)
```

Don't look at what you see... Think this: it means: the first time `i` is greater than `input`. This because we are using integer division, so any number / any smaller number >= 1, while any number / the same number == 1 and any number / a greater number == 0. (the first time because in the `if` there is a `break`, so after the first time, the `for` cycle will end)

```
for(int k = 1; k <= no_of_digits_required-j; k++)
    result = "0" + result;
```

In `j` we had the number of digits of our number, so `no_of_digits_required-j` is the number of `0` padding we need. He is using a `1 <= k <= no_of_digits_required-j`, so base 1, instead of the more classical `0 <= k < no_of_digits_required-j` (base 0)

```
break;
```

We are still inside the `if`. The first time we find how many digits are in our number, we pad it and then we have the "correct" result and we break from the "main" `for`.

Now the only interesting question is why the `Math.pow(10, no_of_digits_required-1)`. The response is easy: if you ask for `no_of_digits_required == 1`, then the cycle is useless, because you won't ever need padding. `i = 10`, `i <= 10^(1-1)` => `i <= 1`, no for cycle. With `no_of_digits_required == 2` we have `i = 10`, `i <= 10^(2-1)` => `i <= 10`, so a single cycle. This is ok, because we have to pad the number only if it's < 10 (so 0...9). The `if (input / i == 0)` will in fact "activate" only for input in the range 0...9... And so on.

I think your ex-colleague is ready for Obfuscated C competitions!

Comment: Well done on the explanation! I tried to get my head around it, but the stupidity of it all made me angry and I couldn't focus. Now I have to spend 20 minutes straightening out the beer can I had to crush, not to mention paying for my neighbors hip replacement, poor thing

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have these WTF moments with code I find hand execution usually helps figure out what is going on.  So here goes appendzeros(3, 3)

result = "3"

i = 10

j = 1

10 <= 100 so run for loop body

if 3 / 10 == 0 (integer division so true)

for k = 1; k <= 2

result = "0" + result

k =2; k <= 2

result = "0"+ result

inner for loop done back to outer for loop

i = 100

j = 2

100 <= 100 so run loop body

if 3 / 100 == 0 true run inner for loop

k = 1

1 <= 1

result = "0" + result

and done "0003"

i, and j both track the same thing(how many digits wide the result is) just in different "number spaces" i tracks it by being that wide in decimal, while j tracks it by counting powers of 10. The if inside the loop gets you to the right power of 10 to start adding zeros.

Answer (score -1):

as I see it,it will insert "0" only if input is 0, and it will add 0 as asked.
this could have been written much better

Comment: This answer is more confusing than the question

Comment: @musefan Obviously the zero input will insert 0 into the insert, obviously only when zero is asked...gawwwddddd!

Comment: @Liam: Ah, when you put it like that...